# Redirect image to specific page url from facebook timeline image using sharer.php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am sharing image using to https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[some_image_link].png. When the user click the images in its facebook timeline it goes to the image path. I want to redirect the user to a particular page like http://www.example.com/page.php#/[some_image_link].
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You should be sharing a link with the OG meta tags that reflects the photo. Then you should be able to see if the request is coming from a crawler (see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler) or a normal user and process the request accordingly.